# textarea + jquery proble

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I made some scripts in JS and connected it to html.

These two pieces of code are the same, but for textarea "name" works and for textarea "about" don't. Please help me!

HTML (it isn't the whole document):

```
<div>
  Назва:
 <textarea type="text" class="form-control" class="name" id="name"></textarea>
 <span class="namme"></span>
</div>

<div>
  Опис товару:
  <textarea type="text" class="form-control" class='about' id='about'></textarea>
  <span class="abbout"></span>
</div>
```

JS:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $("#name").change(function(){
        var name1 = $("textarea#name").val();
        $(this).next('.namme').text("Запам'ятовано");
        createCookie("namme", name1, "1");
    });
    $('.name').trigger('change');



    $('#about').change(function(){
        var about1 = $('#about').val();
        $(this).next('.abbout').text("Запам'ятовано");
        createCookie("abbout", about1, "1");
    });
    $('.about').trigger('change');


});

function createCookie(name, value, days) { 
    var expires; 

    if (days) { 
        var date = new Date(); 
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)); 
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString(); 
    } 
    else { 
        expires = ""; 
    } 

    document.cookie = encodeURIComponent(name) + "=" +  
        encodeURIComponent(value) + expires + "; path=/"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, on my browser your code as is works fine for both textareas, see below snippet:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $("#name").change(function(){
        var name1 = $("textarea#name").val();
        $(this).next('.namme').text("Запам'ятовано");
        createCookie("namme", name1, "1");
    });
    $('.name').trigger('change');



    $('#about').change(function(){
        var about1 = $('#about').val();
        $(this).next('.abbout').text("Запам'ятовано");
        createCookie("abbout", about1, "1");
    });
    $('.about').trigger('change');


});

function createCookie(name, value, days) { 
    var expires; 

    if (days) { 
        var date = new Date(); 
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)); 
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString(); 
    } 
    else { 
        expires = ""; 
    } 

    document.cookie = encodeURIComponent(name) + "=" +  
        encodeURIComponent(value) + expires + "; path=/"; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
        Назва:
        <textarea type="text" class="form-control" class="name" id="name"></textarea>
        <span class="namme"></span>
    </div>

    <div>
        Опис товару:
        <textarea type="text" class="form-control" class='about' id='about'></textarea>
        <span class="abbout"></span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Nevermind, it self-repaired somehow. TY for your answer.

Comment: @J.Doe Could be that the browser was caching the previous version of your Javascript code. A hard reload would have fixed it if it was the case. Just saying in case it happens to you again later on.